# Connecting a STD_LOGIC to a one bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR

Tags: casting, vhdl, xilinx-ise

I'm using Xilinx ISE and generated a memory using the CORE Generator & Architecture Wizard.

The problem is that it created a write enable signal (`wea`) as a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 downto 0) and that results in a type mismatch:

> Line ###: Type error near encnt ; current type std_logic; expected type
>   std_logic_vector

How can I cast `encnt`, which is std_logic, to a one bit std_logic_vector?

(ISE doesn't allow me to change wea from the file of memory.)

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: The VHDL term is type conversion (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.6 Type conversions) where type std_logic (a scalar type) and std_logic_vector (an array type) are not compatible, prompting scary_jeff's use of element association (6.5.6.3 Port clauses, 6.5.7 Association lists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty common scenario with these IP blocks. You can easily associate your `std_logic` signal like this:

```
wea(0) => encnt,
```

Instead of associating `wea` as a whole, you are just associating that one element `(0)`. As `wea` only has one element, this assigns the whole vector.

Comment: Or `wea <= "" & encnt`.

Comment: Or an aggregate: `wea <= (0 => encnt);` noting that for the special case of a single element, only named association works, since positional association is indistinguishable from parentheses around an expression.